# Why are the swap member functions in STL containers not declared noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, noexcept

As of [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) the C++ standard requires `swap` functions of containers to not throw any exceptions unless specified otherwise `[container.requirements.general]` (*23.2.1§10*).

- Why are the `swap` member functions that are specified to not throw not declared `noexcept`?

<sub>The same question applies to the specialized non-member `swap` overloads.</sub>

Comment: My guess is that they missed it probably.

Comment: Which C++ library are you using?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm just looking at the bare standard, not a particular implementation.

Comment: Ah, then I agree with Nawaz.

Comment: That can be helpfull: [link](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/8iksPomni-M/Xk6B2D07tvgJ)

Comment: @ForEveR: I'm copying it into an answer, so that it formally exists within this Q&A.

Comment: A partial answer was given by Nicolai Josuttis in his keynote at C++Now this year; a recording should be available on YouTube soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Further to [what refp said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754223/why-are-the-swap-member-functions-in-stl-containers-not-declared-noexcept/23755126#23755126), here's a post from Daniel Krügler on the `std-discussion` mailing list:

> The internal policy to declare a function as unconditional noexcept is 
>   explained in
>
> http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3279.pdf
>
> With the terminology used in that paper, std::vector's swap function 
>   has a narrowing contract, that is it has preconditions in regard to 
>   the allocators of the participating objects. This means, there exists 
>   the possibility that callers may violate the preconditions and an 
>   implementation should be allowed to signal this my different means 
>   than by termination. Therefore such functions should not be noexcept, 
>   but it should have an effective element "Throws: Nothing" because this 
>   applies to the situation when the preconditions are satisfied.

([link](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!msg/std-discussion/8iksPomni-M/Xk6B2D07tvgJ))

Said internal policy is the canonical, official answer to your question.

Comment: If the caller violates the preconditions, isn't that just a plain bug? If the caller assumes that the `swap()` function cannot throw but it throws anyway (because preconditions are violated), then goodbye exception-safety and preserving invariants. The program may as well `terminate()`.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: Yes, the implementation could do that. The standard is to make _no_ requirements on such a program, though. No requirements. None.

Answer (score 6):

It may sound odd at first, but not explicitly stating that `swap` of standard container  is `noexcept` is intentional; and it all boils down to *undefined behavior* (UB).

---

> `23.2.1p9` **General Container Requirements** `[container.requirements.general]`
>
> > The expression `a.swap(b)`, for containers `a` and `b` of a standard
> >     container type other than `array`, shall exchange the values of `a`
> >     and `b`without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the
> >     individual container elements.
> >
> > Any `Compare`, `Pred`, or `Hash` objects beloning to `a` and `b` shall
> >     be swappable and shall be exchanged by unqualified calls to non-member
> >     `swap`.
> >
> > If
> >     `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`
> >     is `true`, then the allocators of `a` and `b` shall also be exchanged
> >     using an unqalified call to non-member `swap`. *Otherwise, they shall
> >     not be swapped, and the behavior is undefined* unless `a.get_allocator
> >     () == b.get_allocator ().

<sup>**Note**: *italics* added by me.</sup>

---

**Why is the previous section relevant to my question?**

Since the `swap` of standard containers has a precondition (most importantly the last paragraph of the previously quoted section of the Standard), that may lead to *UB* if not satisfied, the Standard doesn't want to impose "impossible" constraints on implementations.

---

The Standard says the following about *undefined behaviour*:

> `1.3.24` **undefined behavior** `[defns.undefined]`
>
> > Behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.

---

Only criminals, and perhaps salesmen, would consider a *No* to be something other than a *No*, but when the Standard says *"no requirements"*  it really means *"**no** requirements"*; marking the relevant `swap` functions as `noexcept` would impose a requirement on implementations, where there should be none.

---

**Why doesn't the Standard want to impose such requirements?**

There's an interesting paper ([N3248](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3248.pdf)) on this matter by *Alisdair Meredith* and *John Lakos* titled "*`noexcept` prevents Library Validation*".

In short it talks about how `noexcept` will prevent library implementation to use `asserts` in library code (ie. implementations of the standard library), even during debug mode, and the implications of that.

If C++ had a standardized *"testing" vs "production" mode* (as the paper calls it), where `noexcept` would conditionally apply, this would be far less problematic.. but as it currently stands; C++ has no "modes".

Comment: Why is swapping allocators along with data problematic?

Comment: That's an interesting take on the definition of UB. Not saying it's wrong.

Comment: @GreenScape I'll fork your comment/question into a new *Q&A*, I'll ping you when it's available.

Comment: @GreenScape this should answer your question: [Why can swapping standard library be problematic involving allocators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23757166/1090079)