# Why can swapping standard library containers be problematic in C++11 (involving allocators)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

<sup>**Note:** Originially asked by [GreenScape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/966376/greenscape) as [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754223/why-are-the-swap-member-functions-in-stl-containers-not-declared-noexcept/23755126?noredirect=1#comment36524813_23755126).</sup>

---

After reading [Why are the swap member functions in STL containers not declared noexcept?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23754223/1090079) it seems that the reason for potential *undefined behavior* when doing `a.swap(b)` for standard containers boils down to also swapping, or not swapping, the underlying allocators.

- Why is swapping allocators along with data problematic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's start of by digging into the Standard ([N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)):

> `23.2.1p9` **General Container Requirements** `[container.requirements.general]`
>
> > If
> >     `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`
> >     is `true`, then the allocators of `a` and `b` shall also be exchanged
> >     using an unqalified call to non-member `swap`. **Otherwise, they shall
> >     not be swapped, and the behavior is undefined unless `a.get_allocator() == b.get_allocator()`**.

---

**What is the purpose of `propagate_on_container_swap`?**

If an Allocator has a *typedef* named `propagate_on_container_swap` that refers to `std::true_type` the underlying Allocators of two containers being swapped, will also swap.<sup>[1]</sup>

If `propagate_on_container_swap` is `std::false_type` only the data of the two containers will swap, but the allocators will remain in their place.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> This means that after `a.swap(b)`, `a.get_allocator()` will be that which was previously `b.get_allocator()`; the allocators has *swapped*.</sup>

---

**What are the implications of stateful Allocators?**

The Allocator is not only responsible for allocating memory for the elements within a Standard container, they are also responsible for the deallocation of said elements.

C++03 didn't allow *stateful allocators* within standard containers, but C++11 mandates that support for such must be present. This means that we could define an allocator that, depending on how it's constructed, acts in a certain way.

If the allocator has `propagate_on_container_swap::value` equal to `false` the difference in state between the two allocators involved might lead to *undefined behavior*, since one instance of the Allocator might not be compatible with the data handled by the other.

---

**What might be the problem with stateful allocators if they are not swapped properly?**

Let's say we have a `MagicAllocator` which either uses `malloc` or `operator new` to allocate memory, depending on how it's constructed.

If it uses `malloc` to allocate memory it must use `free` to deallocate it, and in case of `operator new`, `delete` is required; because of this it must maintain some information saying which of the two it should use.

If we have two `std::vector` which both uses `MagicAllocator` but with different states (meaning that one uses `malloc` and the other `operator new`), and we don't swap the allocators upon `a.swap(b)` the allocator won't match the memory allocated for the elements in the two vectors after the swap - which in terms means that the wrong `free`/`delete` might be called upon deallocation.

Comment: I was unaware of `propagate_on_container_swap`! Thank you for an explanation!

Comment: What is the purpose of supporting `propagate_on_container_swap == false `, seeing as it is defined as causing UB? Also, would it have been possible to mandate a compiler diagnostic iff the UB case occurs?

Comment: @MattMcNabb that's kinda beyond the scope of this question. I can fork it off into a new one, and let you know. it sure is an interesting topic. stay tuned! `;-)`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wrote this one for you: [Why allow `propagate_on_container_swap == false` when it might cause undefined behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23758399/1090079)