# Why allow `propagate_on_container_swap == false` in Allocators, when it might cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, allocator

<sup>**Note:** Originally asked by [Matt Mcnabb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/matt-mcnabb) as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757166/why-can-swapping-standard-library-containers-be-problematic-in-c11-involving#comment36527699_23757167) on [Why can swapping standard library containers be problematic in C++11 (involving allocators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23757166/1090079).</sup>

---

The Standard ([N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) says that if `progagate_on_container_swap` inside an *Allocator* is `std::false_type` it will yield *undefined behaviour* if the two allocators involved doesn't compare equal.

- Why would the Standard allow such construct when it seems more than dangerous?

---

> `23.2.1p9` **General Container Requirements** `[container.requirements.general]`
>
> > If
> >     `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value`
> >     is `true`, then the allocators of `a` and `b` shall also be exchanged
> >     using an unqalified call to non-member `swap`. **Otherwise, they shall
> >     not be swapped, and the behavior is undefined unless `a.get_allocator() == b.get_allocator()`**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<sup>I can think of a few real-life scenarios where the construct allowed by the Standard both makes sense, and is required, however; I'll first try to answer this question from a broader perspective, not involving any specific problem.</sup>

---

**THE EXPLANATION**

*Allocators*  are this magical things responsible for allocating, constructing, destructing, and deallocating memory and entities. Since C++11, when *stateful allocators*  came into play, an allocator can do much more than previously, but it all boils down to the previously mentioned four operations.

*Allocators* have loads of requirements, one of them being that `a1 == a2` (where `a1` and `a2` are allocators of the same type) must yield `true` **only** if memory *allocated* by one can be *deallocated* by the other <sup>[1]</sup>.

The above requirement of `operator==` means that two allocators comparing equal can do things differently, as long as they still have a mutual understanding of how memory is allocated.

The above is why the Standard allows `propagate_on_container_*` to be equal to `std::false_type`; we might want to change the contents of two containers which allocators have the same deallocation behavior, but leave the other behavior (not related to basic memory management) behind.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> as stated in `[allocator.requirements]p2` (table 28)</sup>

---

**THE (SILLY) STORY**

Imagine that we have an *Allocator* named *Watericator*, it gathers water upon requested allocation, and hands it to the requested container.

*Watericator* is a stateful Allocator, and upon constructing our instance we can choose two modes;

1. employ *Eric*, who fetches water down at the fresh water spring, while also measuring (and reporting) water level and purity.
2. employ *Adam*, who uses the tap out in the backyard and doesn't care anything about logging. *Adam* is a lot faster than *Eric*.

No matter where the water comes from we **always** dispose of it in the same way; by watering our plants. Even if we have one instance where *Eric* is supplying us water (ie. memory), and another where `Adam` is using the tap, both *Watericators* compare equal as far as `operator==` is concerned.

Allocations done by one can be deallocated by the other.

<sup>*The above might be a silly simile, but imagine we have an allocator which does logging upon every allocation, and we uses this on a container somewhere in our code that interests us; we later want to move the elements out from this container into another one.. but we are no longer interested in all that logging.*</sup>

<sup>*Without stateful allocators, and the option to turn `propagate_on_container_*` off, we would be forced to either 1) copy every element involved 2) be stuck with that (no longer required) logging.*</sup>

Comment: I so appreciate examples that reference real world things that can be visualized (even if silly), rather than the meaningless `A`, `B`, or `Foo`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not so much that the Standard allows `propagate_on_container_swap` to *cause* Undefined Behavior, but that the Standard *exposes* Undefined Behavior via this value!

---

A simple example is to consider a scoped allocator, which allocates memory from a local pool, and which said pool is deleted when the allocator goes out of scope:

```
template <typename T>
class scoped_allocator;
```

Now, let us use it:

```
int main() {
    using scoped = scoped_allocator<int>;

    scoped outer_alloc;
    std::vector<int, scoped> outer{outer_alloc};

    outer.push_back(3);

    {
        scoped inner_alloc;
        std::vector<int, scoped> inner{inner_alloc};

        inner.push_back(5);

        swap(outer, inner); // Undefined Behavior: loading...
    }

    // inner_allocator is dead, but "outer" refers to its memory
}
```

Comment: I think it would have been easy to either define that such incorrect use of swap simply doesn't compile. Or, even better, that it compiles and works correctly - by copying stuff around instead of simply swapping pointers. So the question is: why wasn't it done like that?

Comment: @PaulGroke: Copying stuff around is usually impossible in C++, because the address of an object is observable, so there is a difference between original and copy (a sharp difference with languages with a compacting GC). I think the standard just punted here... after all, UB gives the implementer the latitude to offer a more useful behavior, such as not compiling, throwing an exception, etc...

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! I didn't think of the fact that many programs will probably rely on the address staying the same after a swap. Also, after asking the question, I realized that not compiling also isn't an option. It would prevent the use of swap in scenarios with defined behavior (=when the two allocator instances are compatible i.e. when they compare equal).
(Not compiling *would* have been an option if the standard said so, but as it is a conforming implementation has to allow it to compile. So I guess that just leaves aborting or throwing.)